# Who are the lost?

Tags: demons-souls

> "Soul of the mind, key to life's ether. Soul of the lost, withdrawn from its vessel. Let strength be granted so the world might be mended... so the world might be mended.”
>
> Her sorrowful, yet tinged-with-hope delivery still sticks with me.

**Who are "*the lost*"? Who is "*her*"?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my speculation:
The lost are those humans without souls, turning into insane monsters.

“Her” is the Maiden in Black, actually a (thus far) benevolent demon who tends the Nexus and aids the player. She is there in the beginning, and facilitates the final battle with the Old One, yet she is apparently sacrificed or consumed in some manner in putting him to slumber (good ending). As a result, I see her as a hopeful, yet sorrowful character.

Comment: I really want to know more about the motivations of the Maiden in Black. Is she a conniving competitor to the Old One? I don’t think so, but it would not surprise me. Rather, I take her as a demon who longs to make right, as if she is not forever damned; I would rather she receives grace because I rather her a sympathetic entity. But I don’t know.

Comment: Delivery,the same as surrender?